# EC2 python file not showing html

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I am installing django for my EC2 instance,

but before I wanted to do this simple test:
i created a file in the instance with the web command line tool

hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
print "Content-Type: text/html" 
print 
print """\ 
<html> 
<body> 
<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
</body> 
</html>
"""
```

and change permissions to execute,

but when I go to my page

```
http://ec2-107-20-20-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hole.py
```

I see the same as the code, not the actual HTML,

but if i do it in other server i actually she the `Hello World!` message

so what im I missing in my EC2 instance to be able to see the python files?

where is the cgi folder? how to create it in my root folder?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) with [Apache 2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) or [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) or [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) with [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) (or another web server) to serve Python web applications. Simply putting a `.py` file somewhere inside your web server's document root won't do what you want, since the web server won't know that it is a script, nor how to execute it (unless you configure CGI appropriately).

WSGI has many advantages over CGI: your application code is loaded once and re-used, rather than re-loaded for each web request; it can be run as a different user than the web server, helping to avoid security issues; it has framework support from lots of Python code and frameworks (including Django); etc.

For more on configuring your Django application for WSGI deployment, see [the Django deployment docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/).